# AngularJS directive with isolated scope doesn't set local scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

This has caught me with a surprise. AngularJS directive is not setting a local scope if it's being used with isolated scope.

I've a amount field which is being validated. The validation message is within a directive which watches for the amount, if greater than 5 it should display an error message. However the error message is not displayed, but the template responses to ng-if which has property declared on local scope.

Below is the code and **[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/01IgmThBFAEzA9LPP5Ik?p=preview)**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {};
});

app.directive('errorMessage', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'my-template.tpl.html',
    scope: {
      amount: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.isAmountError = true;
      scope.$watch('amount', function() {
        if (scope.amount > 5) {
          scope.isAmountError = true;
          scope.errorText = 'Amount lesser than 5';
        } else {
          scope.isAmountError = false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Why do you have `replace: true` set?  If you delete this line, all is working.

Comment: @DavinTryon that is even stranger. Why should it matter?

Comment: It almost feels like with the isolate scope, it won't let you.... oh wait a minute, I think that's it. Nope, not.

Comment: What replace: true ? how does that matter ? Yeah it's working though. But what's the difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `ng-if`. From the API page at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

```
Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored.
```

So each time `ng-if` is evaluating to `true`, a new scope is created which does not reference your `errorText`. On the other hand, if you use `ng-show`, it hides/shows but keeps the scope, and all works fine.

```
<div class="row" ng-show="isAmountError">
```

Here is the updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/BsSueLNpWA8XveyxblmE?p=preview

Comment: Interesting that if you reference `{{$parent.errorText}}` it works with `ng-if`.  This supports the idea that a new child scope is created.

Comment: Looking at the number of error templates which I have. I've opted for ng-if instead of ng-show. I don't want the DOM to be loaded for each and every validation.

Comment: OK. But that definitely was the source of the issue.